# Encadenar dos llamadas a $resource para actualizar dos entidades relacionadas

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo dos entidades relacionadas (Expedición y Temperatura) y necesito guardar la temperatura cuando creo una nueva expedición.

Este es el código que tengo actualmente:

```
angular.module('nowLocateApp').controller('ExpedicionDialogController',
['$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', 'entity',     'Expedicion', 'Camion', 'Delegacion',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $uibModalInstance, entity,   Expedicion, Camion, Delegacion,Temperatura) {

    $scope.expedicion = entity;
    $scope.camions = Camion.query();
    $scope.delegacions = Delegacion.query();
    $scope.load = function(id) {
        Expedicion.get({id : id}, function(result) {
            $scope.expedicion = result;
        });
    };
   $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.isSaving = true;
        if ($scope.expedicion.id != null) {
            Expedicion.update($scope.expedicion, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
        } else {
            Expedicion.save($scope.expedicion, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
            $scope.temperatura.expedicion = $scope.expedicion.id;
            $scope.temperatura.temperatura = 10;
            Temperatura.save($scope.temperatura);
        }
    };

}]);
```

Se puede ver en código completo es mi repositorio de GitHub, espero puedan ayudarme.

https://github.com/AlexMolero/NowLocate/blob/master/src/main/webapp/scripts/app/entities/expedicion/expedicion-dialog.controller.js

Comment: Hi, @alex moreno! This site is purely in Spanish, consider translating your question into Spanish or migrating it to the site in English https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esta redactada en Ingles

Comment: Me tome el tiempo de traducir la pregunta, espero puedan revisarla antes de cerrarla.

Comment: Disculpad por redactarla en ingles, pensé que así podría llegar a mas gente. Gracias de todos modos

Comment: Si, efectivamente podría llegar a mas gente, también podrías probar aquí http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Hola, he realizado unos cambios en tu pregunta, creo que así se entenderá mejor y también he mejorado el título. Creo la forma de redactar las preguntas influye mucho en la ayuda que podamos obtener de la comunidad y que es importante que se entienda lo mejor posible. Espero que no te importe y que no le haya cambiado el sentido. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es encadenar dos llamadas a $resource para actualizar dos entidades relacionadas (Expedición y Temperatura) porque necesitas el identificador único de la nueva Expedición para poder guardar la temperatura.

Para hacer esto tienes que utilizar el resultado del método `save` y acceder a la promise con `$promise`

```
$scope.save = function () {
    $scope.isSaving = true;
    if ($scope.expedicion.id != null) {
        Expedicion.update($scope.expedicion, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
    } else {
        var saveResult = Expedicion.save($scope.expedicion, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
        saveResult.$promise.then(function(savedData) {
            $scope.temperatura.expedicion = savedData.id;
            $scope.temperatura.temperatura = 10;
            Temperatura.save($scope.temperatura);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido de ayuda!!

Comment: De nada @alexmolero, me alegro que te haya servido